# ¿Por qué no se puede buscar el caracter "[" usando LIKE en SQL server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Deseo buscar la apertura del corchete pero no lo reconoce como un caracter:

```
SELECT *
FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
WHERE CharName like '%[%'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que los corchetes, al igual que el %, tienen un significado especial en las condiciones LIKE. Se utiliza para indicar que un carácter tiene que coincidir con un conjunto de caracteres.

Por ejemplo:

```
WHERE campo LIKE '[a-f]ero'
```

cumplirá la condición con valores 'aero', 'bero', 'cero', 'dero', 'eero' y 'fero'.

Para buscar un carácter comodín en una expresión LIKE deberás utilizar precisamente los corchetes. En tu caso:

```
SELECT * FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars WHERE CharName like '%[[]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Quizás se puede solucionar de la siguiente manera:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars
 WHERE CharName like '%\[%'
```

Prueba y nos comentas.